# Display PNG Byte Array in ImageView

Tags: java, android

Afternoon all.

I am trying to display a PNG image in an ImageView on my mobile android application. The image comes in the form of a byte array from a database.

I'm new to android development, so I'm not sure as to the correct way to go about this. I have tried saving the file and setting the image using the URI but to no success.

```
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("NewsImage", lastNewsDTO.ImageExt, null);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    fos.write(lastNewsDTO.Image)
    ((ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivNewsImage)).setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
```

Am I on the right lines or is there a better method?

Thanks for reading, help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you have a `byte[]` that contains a PNG, use [`BitmapFactory` and its `decodeByteArray()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) to convert that into a `Bitmap`. Then, [call `setImageBitmap()` on the `ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) with that `Bitmap`.

Do not write things to disk that do not need to be written to disk.

Comment: Thanks for the comment CommonsWare, see my reply to Harshad. I already tried that method prior, and I was also weary of writing to disk.

Comment: @horHAY: "The Bitmap instance is null when I debug and step over that line of code" -- then, apparently, it is not a valid PNG.

Comment: I've added the image and its definitely a PNG?

Comment: @horHAY: `BitmapFactory` apparently isn't liking it, which usually comes about if the input data is not a valid image (e.g., it's a base64-encoded rendition of the image).

Comment: @CommonWare Cheers dude, I've sussed it. Added the image to the database as a Base64 string then just decoded it on the android side and its working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Use this :

```
byte[] data;

public static void setImageViewWithByteArray(ImageView view, byte[] data) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting Harshad. I tried this method prior to the above code but no success. The Bitmap instance is null when I debug and step over that line of code. Also, not sure if this matters, the image was added to the database using C#, could that impact the ByteArray at all? Cheers.